# How do you type vue-router meta attribute to be required?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router

I have typed the vue-router meta fields according to the manual, for example:

```js
declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface RouteMeta {
    // must be declared by every route
    requiresAuth: boolean
  }
}
```

These meta fields *must* be configured by the developer. Making it non-null ensures that typescript throws an error if `meta` is defined but `requiresAuth` isn't. However, it does not check if `meta` is defined and if it isn't, there are no errors.

How do I make sure that `meta` is defined for every route?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a good practice to modify global behaviour for local purposes. Routes array can have custom type that fits the expectations. E.g. for routes with mandatory `name` and `meta` it's something like:

```
interface RouteCommonMeta {
  ...
}

interface RouteCommonDef {
  name: RouteRecordName;
  meta: IRouteCommonMeta;
  children?: RouteDef[];
}

export type RouteDef = RouteRecordRaw & RouteCommonDefinition;


const routes: RouteDef[] = [...];
```